# How do I calculate big O notation for my recursive function?

Tags: java, recursion, big-o

I want to analyse a few recursive methods but i'm unsure of how to do that. An example of the method is:

```
public static String tree2prefix(LinkedBinaryTree<String> tree) throws IllegalArgumentException {

        if (tree == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Tree was null");
        }

        if (!isArithmeticExpression(tree)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Tree is not a valid arithmetic expression");
        }

        return tree2prefix(tree.root(), tree);

    }

    private static String tree2prefix(Position<String> p, LinkedBinaryTree<String> tree) {
        if (tree == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Tree was null");
        }

        String prefix = "";
        String element = p.getElement();
        prefix += element;

        if (element.equals("+") || element.equals("-") || element.equals("*")) {
            prefix += " " + tree2prefix(tree.left(p), tree) + " ";
            prefix += tree2prefix(tree.right(p), tree);
        }

        return prefix;

    }
```

Can anyone help me understand how to analyse and find the worst case running time for this and other similar methods. Thanks!

Edit:

Would the time complexity be different if for example:

instead of

```
    if (element.equals("+") || element.equals("-") || element.equals("*")) {
        prefix += " " + tree2prefix(tree.left(p), tree) + " ";
        prefix += tree2prefix(tree.right(p), tree);
    }
```

It was:

```
        prefix += tree2prefix(tree.left(p), tree) + tree2prefix(tree.right(p), tree)
```

Comment: How many points do i earn if i get the right answer ? Sounds like a homework to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here as you can see the the time complexity is `O(n)`. Space complexity in the worst case would be `O(n)` in case the tree is skewed.

**Why `O(n)`?**

Because you need to traverse each and every node of the tree.

**Why time complexity is `O(n)` in worst case?**

The recursive call can have at the most of the order of `n` depth.

Here the complexity of the tree to prefix algorithm is considered.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Would the time complexity be different if for example: tree2prefix(tree) + tree2prefix(tree) ?

Comment: It would be same @Nicholasmita